# Docker invalid reference format error when installing laravel sail

Tags: laravel, docker

I am trying to install a new Laravel project using the code provided in the official Laravel documentation

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

However, I keep receiving this error:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
bash: line 16: cd: example-app: No such file or directory
```

I have tried both resetting my Docker application to default factory settings and uninstalling and reinstalling it, but the error keeps reappearing. What makes it even weirder, roughly a month ago I was doing the same thing when first experimenting with Laravel and Docker and everything was working fine. Does anybody know what could be the case?

Comment: "*`... cd: example-app: No such file or directory`*" - Within the contatner, in the current working directory, there is no directory `example-app`.

Comment: Asking to debug a `curl ... | bash` shell script error is the same as a link only question. If in the future the link changes, this question will be useless to others. It's best to include the script being debugged, and reduce the issue to a [mcve] rather than pasting the entire script verbatum.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL), try executing `bash`, because it seems like your device doesnt recognize the docker container.

if that doesnt work, check if php, composer and docker are installed correctly, and if you have downloaded and configured a distro such as Ubuntu.

If the issue still is not fixed, execute `wsl --setdefault -(NAMEOFDISTRO)` in the terminal.

I ran into this same issue a couple of weeks ago and fixed it by using combinations of the solutions above.

I hope this helped!